# Use Ethernet ENC 28 on FEZ Ghi Gadgeteer

Tags: c#, ethernet, raptor, gadgeteer

I have an FEZ Raptor with a ENC28 modul Ethernet.

I would like to send data of my web site to the FEZ Raptor.

My web site is on a Wamp server (installed on my PC) and, the FEZ Raptor is connected to my PC with the ENC 28 modul with a RJ45.
How can I send data, and receive this data with the ENC28 and use this data on my FEZ Raptor program.

Comment: Do you want to use a http connection, use ftp, or create a tcp connection?

Comment: I think for a TCP server on the ethernet enc28 and for a TCP Client for the web site

Comment: See these samples : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=vs.110).aspx